# Simple Olap Cube and simple query MDX

Tags: mdx, pentaho, olap, mondrian

I have a sample star schema made in this way:

```
author (id, name)
book (id, name)
sample_fact_table (id, authorfk, bookfk, quantity)
```

where obiouvsly authorfk is a FK to author.id and bookfk is FK to book.id.

Dimensions are: "author", "book". Measure is "quantity".

I made this configuration for the cube, using Pentaho Schema Workbench tool:

```
<Schema name="MySchema">
  <Dimension type="StandardDimension" visible="true" name="Author">
    <Hierarchy visible="true" hasAll="true" allMemberName="All Authors" primaryKey="id">
      <Table name="author">
      </Table>
      <Level name="Name" visible="true" table="author" column="id" nameColumn="name" uniqueMembers="false">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
  </Dimension>
  <Dimension type="StandardDimension" visible="true" name="Book">
    <Hierarchy visible="true" hasAll="true" allMemberName="All Books" primaryKey="id">
      <Table name="book">
      </Table>
      <Level name="Name" visible="true" table="book" column="id" nameColumn="name" uniqueMembers="false">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
  </Dimension>
  <Cube name="TestCube" visible="true" cache="true" enabled="true">
    <Table name="sample_fact_table">
    </Table>
    <DimensionUsage source="Author" name="Author" visible="true" foreignKey="authorfk">
    </DimensionUsage>
    <DimensionUsage source="Book" name="Book" visible="true" foreignKey="bookfk">
    </DimensionUsage>
    <Measure name="quantity" column="quantity" aggregator="sum" visible="true">
    </Measure>
  </Cube>
</Schema>
```

If I try to execute the MDX query:

```
select 
Measures.quantity ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY Author.Children ON ROWS
from [TestCube]
```

I have a good result:

```
Axis #0:
{}
Axis #1:
{[Measures].[quantity]}
Axis #2:
{[author].[Al]}
{[author].[John]}
{[author].[Jack]}
Row #0: 3
Row #1: 9
Row #2: 1
```

But if instead of Author I query on Book, like this:

```
select 
Measures.quantity ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY Book.Children ON ROWS
from [TestCube]
```

I get this error:

```
Mondrian Error:Failed to parse query 'select 
Measures.quantity ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY Book.Children ON ROWS
from [TestCube]'

Mondrian Error:MDX object 'Book' not found in cube 'TestCube'
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Author and Book are both Dimensions, both declared in the same way, both referenced into the Cube.

Thank you!

Comment: if you take author out of the cube definition, and leave book's definition in, does the book query execute ok?

Comment: it still didn't execute query, also taking out author, giving that error.
I got stuck for a couple of hours, then I tried the same thing on another computer, with the same database, the same xml and the same client tool, and it worked as expected.
I still can't figure out what the problem was.